# How to add images to div bubbles using CSS

Tags: css

The codes below shows left and right bubbles. How do I add left and right images to the chat bubbles tooltip respectively using CSS?

### Screenshot updates

Added screenshot showing what am trying to implement. The left.png image on the left side of the chat bubbles and right.png on the right.

[image: screenshot]

Below is the left and right image that I want to add to the chat **bubbles**

```
  <img src="right.png" width="20px" height="20px">
    <img src="left.png" width="20px" height="20px">
```

**Below is the Code so far.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #00bfb6;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}


/* right bubble */

.right:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  right: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}


/* left bubble */

.left:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3 right">right bubble using css</div>

<div class="box3 left">left bubble using css</div>
```

Comment: use `background-image:url('yourimage');`

Comment: background approach is not good. what if the image is coming from database

Comment: It would then pick the image from the database in the same way than if you link the image on the HTML sheet. Why are you worried about an image coming from database? There not really any issues involving background images and the origin of the img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping your bubble + your image in a flex container is a great and easy way to place them together and have some flexibility to move the elements around. `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` is basically enough to achieve it. View snippet below.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container {
    /*ADDED*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 60px 0;
}
img {
    /*ADDED*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
#img-right {
    /*ADDED*/
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#img-left {
    /*ADDED*/
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.box3 {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #00bfb6;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
}
/* right bubble */

.right:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid #00bfb6;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    right: -16px;
    top: 0px;
}
/* left bubble */

.left:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #00bfb6;
    border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    left: -16px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box3 right">
        right bubble using css
    </div>
    <img id="img-right" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/kairos-media/team/Ben_Virdee-Chapman.jpeg"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img id="img-left" src="https://cdn.madaracosmetics.com/media/catalog/category/FACE_OK_3.jpg"/>
    <div class="box3 left">
        left bubble using css
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the image inside the bubble and use absolute position to get the correct position.

Relevant code:

```
.box3 > img {
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
}

.right > img {
  left:calc(100% + 20px);
}
.left > img {
  right:calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

Full code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #00bfb6;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}
.box3 > img {
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
}

.right > img {
  left:calc(100% + 20px);
}
.left > img {
  right:calc(100% + 20px);
}

/* right bubble */

.right:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  right: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}


/* left bubble */

.left:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3 right"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069">right bubble using css</div>

<div class="box3 left"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069">left bubble using css</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will complete it in a few years, as a puzzle.. :-P

HTML

```
<div class="box3 right-up"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069">right bubble using css</div>
<div class="box3 right-down"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069">right bubble using css</div>
<div class="box3 left"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069">left bubble using css</div>
```

CSS

```
    * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #00bfb6;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}
.box3 > img {
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
}

.right-up > img {
display:none;
}
.right-down > img {
  left:calc(100% + 20px);
}
.left > img {
  right:calc(100% + 20px);
}

/* right-up bubble */

.right-up {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.right-up:before {
  margin: 20px auto;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid #00bfb6;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  right: -16px;
  top: 33px;
}

.right-down {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.right-down:before {
  margin: 20px auto;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  right: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}


/* left bubble */

.left:before {
  margin: 20px auto;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-top: 15px solid #00bfb6;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I have much experience I complete this